# Querying MySQL and MSSQL databases at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm getting data from an MSSQL DB ("A") and inserting into a MySQL DB ("B") using the date created in the MSSQL DB. I'm doing it with simple logics, but there's got to be a faster and more efficient way of doing this. Below is the sequence of logics involved:

1. Create one connection for MSSQL DB and one connection for MySQL DB.
2. Grab all of data from A that meet the date range criterion provided.
3. Check to see which of the data obtained are not present in B.
4. Insert these new data into B.

As you can imagine, step 2 is basically a loop, which can easily max out the time limit on the server, and I feel like there must be a way of doing this must faster and during when the first query is made. Can anyone point me to right direction to achieve this? Can you make "one" connection to both of the DBs and do something like below?

```
SELECT * FROM A.some_table_in_A.some_column WHERE 
   "it doesn't exist in" B.some_table_in_B.some_column
```

Answer (score 3):

A [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) might suit this

> A linked server allows for access to distributed, heterogeneous
>   queries against OLE DB data sources. After a linked server is created,
>   distributed queries can be run against this server, and queries can
>   join tables from more than one data source. If the linked server is
>   defined as an instance of SQL Server, remote stored procedures can be
>   executed.

Check out [this HOWTO](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008) as well

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you're just trying to move things in the MSSQL DB into the MySQL DB.  I'm also assuming there is some sort of filter criteria you're using to do the migration.  If this is correct, you might try using a stored procedure in MSSQL that can do the querying of the MySQL database with a distributed query.  You can then use that stored procedure to do the loops or checks on the database side and the front end server will only need to make one connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL database has a primary key defined, you can at least skip step 3 ("Check to see which of the data obtained are not present in B"). Use [`INSERT IGNORE INTO...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and it will attempt to insert all the records, silently skipping over ones where a record with the primary key already exists.